How do I preverify my lock code when using google pay?
When I go to pay with Google pay, I take my phone out of my pocket, I unlock it and then I tap the eftpos machine. Then my phone says please verify and I have to enter my phone's code, then I can tap again.
This is pretty annoying since it usually also cancels the transaction and the vendor has to redo the eftpos machine.
Is there some way to pre-verify?

It seems like in one of the recent updates this functionality has been added. You can now do this by opening the wallet app, after half a second a box should appear near the top with a button to "verify that it's you", this will also appear if you click on any of the cards. Just click it and enter your pin or fingerprint. Then you will be able to tap without verifying.

Does your phone support Fingerprint or Face Unlock? Or try unlocking your phone just before you reach the terminal.

The question states that the phone is unlocked before reaching the terminal.

ye I've tried unlocking it immediately before paying but it doesn't matter, still need to fail first
